# Как реализовать анимацию появления текста?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Сделал такой код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h79dj2sa/11/). Нужно сделать как здесь [cssanimation](http://cssanimation.io/index.html) анимация **Blur In**.

Текст будет появляться с помощью картинок, а не текста, в этом и проблема.
Не могу понять что не так делаю?

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.fn.fade_img = function(ops) {
      var $elem = this;
      var res = $.extend({
        delay: 400,
        speed: 800
      }, ops);
      for (var i = 0, pause = 0, l = $elem.length; i < l; i++, pause += res.delay) {
        $elem.eq(i).delay(pause).fadeIn(res.speed).animate({
          'opacity': 1
        }, 400).css({
          'filter': 'blur(0px)'
        })
      }
      return $elem;
    };
    $('.sector-one__fade').fade_img();
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.sector-one__logo {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  display: flex;
  width: 765px;
}

.sector-one__logo span {
  width: 30px;
}

.sector-one__fade {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 30px;
  animation: leBlurIn 2s linear;
}

@keyframes leBlurIn {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0.2);
    filter: blur(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="sector-one__logo">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <span></span>
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sector-one__fade" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/a8/54/f1a85455da01f580256ec48fee16fff5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```